# What is the default initialization of a std::istream object?

Tags: c++

I am reading Bjarne's "The C++ Programming Language" 4th edition book and I've stumbled on page 438. It speaks about header file organization and global variable initialization.

```
//lexer.cpp
#include "lexer.h"

Lexer::Token_stream is;    // defaults to "read from cin"
```

The namespace Lexer look like this:

```
//lexer.h
namespace Lexer {

    class Token_stream {
        public:
            Token_stream(istream& s) : ip{&s}, owns{false} {}
            Token_stream(istream* p) : ip{p},  owns{true}  {}
            Token get() {
                 
                char ch = 0;
                *ip >> ch;
                /*...*/
            }
            /*...*/
        private:
            istream* ip;
            bool owns;
            /*...*/
    }
    extern Token_stream is;
}
```

I've seen the `Token_stream` class and it doesn't have a default constructor. So does the line

`Lexer::Token_stream is;    //defaults to "read from cin"`

mean that he implemented a default constructor for the class `Token_stream` but he didn't write it in the book or am I missing something ?

Comment: must be part of the `/*...*/`.  Normally source code is included on a disk or a link of some sort.  that will probably have the full code in it.  From what I've seen he trims down code in the book so that less space is "wasted" with boilerplate code.

Comment: Why do you think the existence or not of `basic_istream`s default constructor is relevant?

Comment: @molbdnilo Seems to be a typo by OP. It should be `Token_stream`?

Comment: @user12002570 Perhaps. There's also the "std::istream" in the title, and two completely different major typos seemed unlikely.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that the istream represents a pointer to an object, my mistake.

Comment: @EdmondDantes That makes more sense.

Comment: @molbdnilo It was a typo, confirmed by OP.

Comment: I mean it must be what @NathanOliver said, that he just left it out and I misinterpreted everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does the line `Lexer::Token_stream is;    //defaults to "read from cin"`
> mean that he implemented a default constructor for the class Token_stream **but he didn't write it in the book**

Yes, the default constructor `Token_Lexer::Token_Lexer()` is needed for `Lexer::Token_stream is;` to work and that ctor has not been explicitly provided in the book example. In other words the default ctor must be part of the other code specified as `/*...*/` inside the class.

Usually these books come with a CD-ROM that contains all the source code of different compete working examples.